# Symfony 6 - loading fixtures in not possible because of SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7

Tags: symfony, fixtures

I made two entities: "Personne" and "Famille". Personne entity has properties: firstname, lastname, age and Famille entity has side property.

I'm using orm-fixtures and fzaninotto/faker to create fake data.

How I did it:

Firstly I made Personne entity then created the data using:

```
Symfony console make:fixture
```

and

```
Symfony console doctrine:fixture:load
```

which worked well.

Then I proceed to do the same with Famille entity but then at:

```
Symfony console doctrine:fixture:load
```

I got the error:

> In ExceptionConverter.php line 71:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42P01]:
> Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation « famille » doesn't exist
> LINE 1: DELETE FROM famille
> ^
>
> In Exception.php line 28:
>
> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation « famille »
> doesn't exist     LINE 1: DELETE FROM famille
> ^
>
> In Connection.php line 31:
>
> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation « famille »
> doesn't exist     LINE 1: DELETE FROM famille
> ^

But I don't understand because I have no relation now. I tried to make OneToOne relation between Personne and Famille entities but I had this error and then tried again without the relation OneToOne but the error is still here. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to do the migrations again, so:

```
symfony console make:migration
symfony console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```